# Write test to method in controller

Tags: java, spring, testing

I am trying to test method in controller but don't have idea how to can I do this proper

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{name}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody void exportLeadsToCSV(HttpServletResponse httpResponse, @PathVariable String name) {
    S3Object s3Object = fileService.getS3File(name);
    if (s3Object != null) {
        try {
            InputStream targetStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
            ServletOutputStream out = httpResponse.getOutputStream();

            httpResponse.setContentType("application/csv");
            httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);

            IOUtils.copyLarge(targetStream, out);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I actually wanted to mock somehow fileService to return file from localstorage as S3File and use MockMvc to trigger this

my tried looks like:

```
@Test
public void testReturnFile() throws IOException {
        Mockito.when(fileUploadService.getS3File(PATH_TO_FILE)).thenReturn(s3Object);
        Mockito.when(s3Object.getObjectContent()).thenReturn(s3ObjectInputStream);

        // how to mock my local file as s3Object content?
    }
```

Comment: There are some s3 mocking solutions, check this out for example: https://github.com/findify/s3mock

Comment: this is mocking whole s3 service, I'd like to somehow mock only s3Object

Comment: I'm not familiar with `S3Object`, but have you tried `Mockit.mock(S3Object.class)`? If it doesn't work (e.g. because it's final), you may consider reworking (or wrapping) the "file service", so that it just returns the needed `InputStream`, which you can then replace in your test.

Answer (score 1):

Try using @Mock where we declare instance variable.
For more details, you can refer to this link.
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations#mock-annotation